# How to add asp-subarea to form tag helpers in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm developing an asp.net core 2.2 project and due to hierarchy of menu levels I had to create subareas (Controllers, views, etc.), so I followed a [c-sharpcorner article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/expanding-razor-view-location-and-sub-areas-in-asp-net-core/) relate with that and it worked succeded, however article doesn't mention about creation of **asp-subarea** form attribute tag helper, I read about [Microsoft author tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but is not very clear for me since asp-subarea depends on other attributes like **asp-area** and **asp-controller** to build the final action attribute into the form tag.

I'd appreciate any help about. Thanks